# Server 2012 R2 RDSH repeated high modified memory causing OS issues

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-esxi, memory-usage, remote-desktop-services

We have multiple 2012 R2 remote desktop session hosts running on ESXi 6.5U1, and have noticed this week that most of these VMs have started experiencing an issue whereby;

Repeatedly through the day for durations of several minutes at a time, the modified memory usage shown in task manager shoots up through the roof to 18GB or more (depending on VM memory assignment and active memory), and sits at 100 commit.

After a while, the modified memory I guess gets flushed to disk, and the usage then returns to normal.

During this time, the VM becomes almost completely unresponsive. Has anyone experienced this recently and have any thoughts on the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have been a transient issue.

We assigned more memory to each affected VM just in case, but resolved itself before then.